# blank or empty line from input function in python

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop, enter

I have a question. How do I tell the program to end when the user does not enter a value and simply press enter?

```
name=("")
while(name !=  '\n'):
    print( 'Enter first and last name: ')
    name=input().lower()
    if(name !=  '\n'):
        print(name)
    else:
        print("terminado")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `name` when you just hit enter to find out:

```
>>> name = input('Name? ')
Name? Mark
>>> name
'Mark'
>>> name = input('Name? ')
Name?
>>> name
''
```

The new line is not included in the input.

Also, `if name:` is `True` if `name` is not an empty string, so:

```
while True:
    name = input('Name? ')
    if name:
        print(name)
    else:
        print('Done')
        break
```

```
Name? Mark
Mark
Name? Joe
Joe
Name? John
John
Name?
Done
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
while True:
  name = input('Enter first and last name:').lower()
  if not name:
     break
  print("name: %s" % name)
print("terminado")
```

As long as the user doesn't hit "Enter" and does in fact have type the name, the name will be printed, but if "Enter" means basically an empty string `""` is returned then it will return terminado.